# Unable to change Installed platforms for android in apache cordova for visual studio

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to upgrade Installed platforms to android 5.0.0 in Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova project by using Cordova CLI command when i run command debugg path platform will upgrade to 5.0

[consol screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9U8rs.png)
but when i again rebuild project it reset to old version 3.7.2 , yes it will reset to older version when project build but how can i upgraded android version globally so when i build it again it show upgraded android version.

i added this in config file

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="23" />
 <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

installed SDK platform for API 23 in SDK manager but still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the configuration file in your Cordova app, select platform and check the checkbox to use the globally installed cordova CLI version.

This update is available if your have TACO tools update 5 in VS 2015.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so there is no way to solve this in VS2013 update 5?

Comment: They announced this for VS2015, check out the announcement in 1/21/15. link: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/01/21/visual-studio-tools-for-apache-cordova-update-5/  -- It is the recommended version for cordova apps dev. lots of enhancements to comply with cordova CLI standards.

Answer (score 0):

From the cli run: Cordova platform add @.

Comment: do you see screenshot i added ?